# how to display a blob image from a database to a jsp

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Here is my jsp code and my servlet code in getting an image

newJSP.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="newServlet" method="GET">
        id &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="id"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

newServlet

```
@WebServlet("/image/*")
```

public class newServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    LReceiptsDAO lrDAO = new LReceiptsDAO();
    // Get ID from request.
    int imageId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    // Check if ID is supplied to the request.
    if (imageId == 0) {
        // Do your thing if the ID is not supplied to the request.
        // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }

    // Lookup Image by ImageId in database.
    // Do your "SELECT * FROM Image WHERE ImageID" thing.
    byte[] image = lrDAO.getReceiptFile(imageId);

    // Check if image is actually retrieved from database.
    if (image == null) {
        // Do your thing if the image does not exist in database.
        // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }

    // Init servlet response.
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("image/*");
    response.setContentLength(image.length);

    // Write image content to response.
    response.getOutputStream().write(image);
}
```

}

I do not know how to show the image content in another jsp file . Is there a way that I can redirect to the new jsp and show it there thru this code:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        request.setAttribute("ca", c);
        request.setAttribute("bList", bList);
        RequestDispatcher dispatch = context.getRequestDispatcher("/Accounting_CashAdvance_PrepareVoucher.jsp");
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
```

I appreciate those who will be answering my question. Thank you!

Comment: Does your servlet work when you call it directly? It seems to me the content type is supposed to be specific - `image/jpeg`,`image/gif`, `image/png`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a new JSP.
In Body, Just place the img tag.

```
<html>
<body>

<img src="/image"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I do that? I'm very sorry for asking because i'm new to this.